# Update global variable in an asychrounouus way in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a tacky problem. On my website, you can find current price tracker for crypto coins as a purely content filler element. I get my data from coin API, you are allowed 100 request's per day.

```py
def crypto_api_prices(request):
    
    api_base_url = 'https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate/'
    api_key = '==============='

    headers = {
        'X-CoinAPI-Key': api_key,
    }

    crypto_tickers = ["BTC","ETH","ETC","RVN"]
    crypto_api_links = [api_base_url+x+"/"+"USD" for x in crypto_tickers ]
    crypto_api_prices = [requests.get(x, headers=headers).json()['rate'] for x in crypto_api_links]
    context = {
        "cryptoPrices":crypto_api_prices
        }
    return context
```

I'm calling this function in my home view. Unfortunately, if I have couple of visitors daily this generates 100 requests pretty fast and my element isn't working anymore.

What I want to achieve is set crypto_api_prices as a global variable and update it every hour, so no matter how many users will be on my page I will generate only 24 requests.

Is this a good idea? Are there alternatives? Of course I can buy more requests but this website is a "passion" project so I want to keep costs down

Comment: Simple comment i'd say is, since this is a passion project, you shouldn't assume your product is going to need that much scale, or even a 100 requests a day.

Comment: you should keep values in your database/file so different uses will use the same data without sending request to API. And other part of code should periodically send request for new data and add to database. And this code can control and send only 100 requests a day.

Comment: @furas what do you think about setting a cookie for one day per user. Then I can get the JSON data from my endpoint to cookie and put it into my HTML. In theory, I will be good for 100 different users

Comment: i would rather use some caching method to execute `requests` only every ~15minutes (and it would give 100 requests a day). Python has standard [cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) but it doesn't use time but size of data. But there is [requests-cache](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which can cache `requests`.

Comment: but it cache every url separatelly - so for getting 4 coins it would have to use 1hour for every coint. OR maybe you should use [get-all-current-rates](https://docs.coinapi.io/?python#get-all-current-rates-get) to get all coins in one request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do two things:

1. I would use

   ```
   /v1/exchangerate/USD?invert=true
   ```

   to get rates for all tickers in one request

   (doc: https://docs.coinapi.io/?python#get-all-current-rates-get)

   and later I would filter needed tickers. And it would works even if I change list of tickers
2. I would use [requests-cache](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to get results from cache, and make real request only every 15 minutes - so it should give 100 requests a day

---

Minimal working code

```
import os
import requests
import requests_cache
from datetime import timedelta

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES` for constants

API_KEY = os.getenv('COINAPI_TOKEN')

# --- session: cache and API key ---

s = requests_cache.CachedSession(expire_after=timedelta(minutes=15))
#s.cache.clear()  # manually clear cache

s.headers.update({'X-CoinAPI-Key': API_KEY})

# --- every rate separatelly ---

url = 'https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate/{}/USD'

tickers = ["BTC", "ETC", "ETH", "RVN"]

prices = {coin: s.get(url.format(coin)).json()['rate']
            for coin in tickers}

context = {"cryptoPrices": prices}

print(context["cryptoPrices"])

# --- all rates ---

url = 'https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate/USD?invert=True'

response = s.get(url)
data = response.json()

# filter data

tickers = ["BTC", "ETH", "ETC", "RVN"]

prices = {}

for item in data['rates']:
    if item['asset_id_quote'] in tickers:
        key = item['asset_id_quote']
        val = item['rate']
        prices[key] = val

context = {"cryptoPrices": prices}

print(context["cryptoPrices"])
```